# Did spark executor memory overhead includes JVM memory cost?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I run spark on YARN and every executor run in CGroup, for a task I specify the executor memory to 10G, and CGroup memory limit 11G considering executor memory overhead(the default value, 0.1), but it seems that the Java process always tried to use more than 11G memory and then killed by CGroup because that triggered an oom.
So did the 1GB spark executor memory overhead includes all memory cost by JVM? Is there any more memory cost needed? Or should I try to increase CGroup memory limit?
Here is the start command line of my executor and dmesg logs triggering oom:
[the start command line of my executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtHtC.png)
[dmesg logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYjLP.png)